# vi can't set paste(turn off auto indent while paste) in BusyBox

Tags: unix, vi, busybox

`vi` version is **BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-08-27 12:48:18 PDT) multi-call binary**, which run on `esxi` machine.

Can't paste text without auto indent by these methods:

- `:set paste` in `vi` editor
- configure `set noautoindent` in **.vimrc** which located in `$HOME` directory.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BusyBox's `vi` is tiny and doesn't know what `paste` is.

It also isn't VIM, so won't read `.vimrc`, but will read `$HOME/.exrc` if it exists and is only owned and writable by the user. You should be able to put `set noautoindent` there in a more recent version.

You also have the option of placing commands in the `EXINIT` environment variable, or passing them as an additional parameter with `-c "some_command"` (both of which should be implemented in the version you're using, and both of which allow multiple commands separated by `\n`).

I'll note that all of the above depends on `vi` having been built with the `SETOPTS`, `SET` and `COLON` features enabled (though `-c` should work without `COLON`), which should be the default.

The set of options supported by [a current version](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/editors/vi.c?id=c93eb1a95b1f06c145d4169a8776a318a2085e8b) appears to be:

- `autoindent`
- `expandtab`
- `flash`
- `ignorecase`
- `showmatch`
- `tabstop`

Comment: `$HOME/.exrc` can't work with the right privileges which as you say.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't checking your specific version. That version doesn't support `.exrc`, but will read `EXINIT`.

Comment: I can't find `EXINIT` file in the machine. But I found that exec `:set noautoindent` command in `vi` works. Anyway, thanks for you answer.

Comment: `EXINIT` is an environment variable. You could run `EXINIT=':set noautoindent' vi` for example, or set it using `export` before running vi.

Comment: Oh, I see, exec `export EXINIT='set noautoindent'` and `vi` works. THX.